# losing connection to MySQL server when loading 30GB CSV file

Tags: mysql, csv, bulk-load

I'm trying to load a 30GB CSV file into MySQL using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:Documents/CRSP.csv' INTO TABLE rawcrsp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  IGNORE 1 LINES
```

After a few hours of waiting, I get an error: Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

The same code works with a smaller CSV file formatted the exact same way. I'm working in Windows 7. I have 24 GB RAM, and 240 GB free space on my hard drive. Any tips for how to get this to load?

Comment: Can you split the file? I tink you have a problem with the connection timeout.

Comment: Upload it to a local disk first, then load it from there.

Comment: @Jens, I can split the file. I am trying to increase the timeout and packet size, if that fails, I'll experiment with splitting the file.

Comment: @halfer, can you explain what you mean by uploading it to a local disk?

Comment: Ah, I made the assumption that the MySQL server is remote, and now I am not sure. Is it on the same machine as the CSV file? If not, copy the CSV file to the local disk of the database server, and do the `LOAD DATA` from there.

Comment: I see, yeah, the MySQL server is on the same machine as the CSV file. Once I get the CSV file loaded, I'm planning on moving the server to another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 reasons:

1. Check if wait_timeout variable in your configuration file is large enough, if not increase it.
2. If mysqld gets a packet that is too large , it thinks that something is wrong with the client and closes the connection. Try to maximize packet size limit from the configuration file.

Comment: I think the configuration file you're referring to is C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini? I don't see the wait_timeout variable in there.
I do see a max_allowed_packet=4M variable, should I increase that to 400M?

Comment: You can see the server system variables here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout . You can set the wait_time by using: mysql> SET session wait_timeout=3000;(Choose a value) 
You can also try to increase max_allowed_packet to a big number and see if it works.